# My chart splits the two lines independently

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am working on a school project and I have a big issue with my Chart. Basically the Two lines which should be closer together between 11000-13000 keep being split apart and the Red one appears in the wrong position.

Here is a photo:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this? They seem to be independent from each other.

Comment: The red line is meant to be a plot of Yt from Column C?

Comment: The red line is meant to be a plot of YtT (MM ) from Column D. Blue is Yt from Column C

Comment: Looks like you've picked a "Stacked Line Chart" type instead of just a "Line Chart" type.

Comment: Answer added :)

Answer (score 0):

#### The two lines keep being split apart and the Red one appears in the wrong position.

You have chosen the wrong chart type - a "Stacked Line Chart" type instead of a "Line Chart" type.

The key difference is that the Stacked Line Chart **sums** the data.

Below are some examples showing the difference:

> [image]

And

> [image]

Image Source [Excel Charts Line Chart](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/excel_charts/excel_charts_line.htm)

Comment: If this answered your question, please don't forget to [accept the answer](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the accept button (the tick ✓ button)